# Minimize function of many variables

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have the following code that defines the function `f`:

```
def f(a,b,lst,data): 
     #Evaluates some function that depends on parameters a, b, lst and data
     value = #some value calculation
     return value
```

Where `a,b` are float, `lst`  is list and `data` is np.array. I'm trying to minimize this function with respect to `a,b` using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but when I run this

```
lst = #some list
data = #some np.array
scipy.optimize.minimize(f,x0 = [0.1,0.1], args = (lst,data))
```

I'm getting the following error: `f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`

Comment: Your code is not consistent enough to provide a trustworthy picture of what is going on. Please provide an actual MCVE and full stack trace

Comment: Read the `minimize` docs.  How does  it distinguish the minization variable(s) from the ones passed in via `args`?  Specificaly is your 2 element `x0` consistent with the `a,b` args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are defining data outside the function already. Just delete the data object from the function and it will work perfectly.